# Programmatically generating a 3D map based on Data

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d

I want to generate a 3D city/marketplace map based on data that I collect from different text. For every text I read, I want to automatically create a new map - a map that the user can interact with. 
The data extracted will be based on 12 categories and then further attributes. I want to represent the categories as streets and the attributes as building. 
However, according to different text, I may have different number of categories and attributes.
I wanted to use unity to create the map, but as the map is dynamic, I am not sure exactly how to implement the construction.

Is it possible to programmatically generate a 3D map based on data on unity? If not, is there another way I can do this?

Comment: Can you please give an example of the kind of input text you'd like to generate the map from? How should the map look? What are its properties?

Comment: by '3D Map' do you mean a 'Terrain' or a 'Mesh' or a 3D array of separate gameobjects like minecraft?